# Is there a way to select last N columns in SQL Server Results Tab?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2014, ssms-2014

**Shortly,**

**I don't** mean the last 5 rows. via `SELECT TOP 5 * FROM Table Order By Key DESC`

But I mean last 5 columns in Results Tab.  [image]

Why? because each time I add a new column and filling it outside SQL-Server, I need to see its result without moving Horizontal Scroll. and many columns have the same name at the beginning.

It's not coding issues. but it's about the SQL-Server IDE Results tab itself.

> I Searched many times. but this thing never asked I think. so please I
>   want an approach for that. I assume something like built-in function
>   or something anyone knows

Comment: No, that is not possible

Comment: Yes, don't use `*` and define the names of the columns in your `SELECT` instead.

Comment: Are you sure? should i delete question now -.-

Comment: Lamu if each time i re-write columns. i should turn-off PC instead. there's many new columns added.

Comment: Type in the name of the columns that you want to see. How difficult is that?

Comment: Select the query, press CTRL + SHIFT + Q, then in the designer view unselect all columns except the last 5.

Comment: L A **R N** U, @deveton . Why is your table constantly changing definition...? The definition of a specific object should be pretty static; if it's changing each time you connect to the server, that implies a far larger design problem.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to see the last columns added? I would do it like this `SELECT TOP 5 COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Settings' ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION DESC`

Comment: Birel, no the last columns printed in results tab.

Comment: That means you will have to change your query to dynamic SQL...

Comment: Panagiotis, sorry its by wrong. for refining it

Comment: If you want to query stuff (filter, select, aggregate by it). it should be in its own field. If you have stuff that don't take part in queries you *could* stuff them in an XML or JSON field. SQL Server allows up to 30K sparse columns per table using XML fiels for storage. You can still query those values when needed, eg with JSON_VALUE. If they're used regularly though, they should be fields

Comment: @deveton I cant' stress enough what kind of hell SharePoint's database is, or how *expensive* it is to insert or query stuff. 5000 items per list are a *lot*, precisely because the data has to be pulled from an EAV table and rehydrated in code. Forget about indexing.  In a database table though 5M rows are peanuts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like I mentioned in the comments, if your table's definition is constantly changing this suggests a far larger design flaw in your database. Object definitions should be pretty static, and they should definitely not be changing every time you connect to the instance. That is the root cause of your problem, not that it's "too difficult", to type the name of 5 columns, rather than using `*`.

This means fixing your design, which we can't comment on, but I suggest that is your next **major** step to do. Normalise your design, and use multiple tables (as I suspect you're adding extra columns each time due to a lack of normalisation).

In the interim, you can use dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

DECLARE @Schema sysname = N'dbo',
        @Table sysname = N'rCTE_Vs_Tally';

SET @SQL = N'SELECT ' +
           STUFF((SELECT TOP(5)
                         N',' + @CRLF + 
                         N'       ' + QUOTENAME(c.[name])
                  FROM sys.schemas s
                       JOIN sys.tables t ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
                       JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
                  WHERE s.[name] = @Schema
                    AND t.[name] = @Table
                  ORDER BY C.column_id DESC
                  FOR XML PATH(N''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,10,'') + @CRLF + 
          N'FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@Schema) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@Table) + @CRLF + 
          N'ORDER BY [Key] DESC;' --Assumes all tables have the column Key
PRINT @SQL;


EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Comment: idk, why all answers contains    FOR XML PATH(

Comment: Because you're using SQL Server 2014, @deveton , not 2017; thus you don't have access to `STRING_AGG`.

Comment: omg, i don't really understand. i expect a select last columns from target table. i don't like complicated query. can you mention what benefits of FOR XML Path or string_agg and why you use that ?

Comment: *"i don't really understand. i expect a select last columns from target table"* That's what this does. As I said in the answer, the ***real*** problem is your constantly changing design and why you need a more complex solution to do something that should be incredibly simply. `FOR XML PATH` is doing to job of `STRING_AGG` here, due to you using an older version. You can find out about `STRING_AGG` in the [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). At the end of the day, fix your design; that's the *real* solution @deveton

Comment: Well, ok I will keep this open till a batman come and explode us with an un-query version, maybe we all surprised. ^^

Comment: I'm not angry at all, @deveton, just telling you the fact of the matter, I'm afraid.  If you *really* want the functionality, you could ask on the Official SQL Server forums. it *might* then be added in a future version of SQL Server, but it certainly won't be added in 2014 I'm afraid; which is now only in extended support.

Comment: Sounds like that shouldn't be a new column each time, @deveton . You should be adding a new row in your table; which has 2(+) columns. A `SettingName` column, and a `SettingValue` column (plus other related columns). Considering you want to know the "latest" setting, a date(time) column is probably a good idea too. If your settings aren't for ever expanding, the design you have isn't a problem, but the fact that they are means that you should be building tall, not wide.

Comment: LARNU, each setting have custom data-type, so adding new row will have same type of column.

Comment: Then you either need to cement your settings or use dynamic SQL to achieve your goal (as that is the only way). You *could* (and this isn't recommendation, just saying you *could*) use a `sql_variant` column, but it does come with learning curve and caveats; and that isn't a discussion point for the comments I'm afraid.

Answer (score 3):

Probably a dynamic statement, based on system catalog views, may help here:

```
DECLARE @tablename sysname = 'table'
DECLARE @schemaname sysname = 'dbo'
DECLARE @stm nvarchar(max) 

SELECT @stm = (
    SELECT TOP(5) CONCAT(@stm, N',', col.[name])
    FROM sys.columns col
    JOIN sys.tables tab ON col.object_id = tab.object_id
    JOIN sys.schemas sch ON tab.schema_id = sch.schema_id
    WHERE 
        tab.[name] = @tablename AND 
        sch.[name] = @schemaname
    ORDER BY col.column_id DESC
    FOR XML PATH('')
)
SELECT @stm = CONCAT(
    N'SELECT ',
    STUFF(@stm, 1, 1, N''),
    N' FROM ',
    QUOTENAME(@schemaname),
    N'.',
    QUOTENAME(@tablename)
)

PRINT @stm
EXEC sp_executesql @stm
```

Comment: Because you're using SQL Server 2014, not 2017, @deveton

Comment: `XML PATH('')` is used here to aggregate strings (columns names). If you use SQL Server 2017, `STRING_AGG()` will be more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Ok Deveton, as explained, a Dynamic SQL is needed for this.

I think the below would answer your question:

```
declare @columns    varchar(max)
,       @sql        varchar(max)
,       @tblname    varchar(20)     =   'Settings'

select @columns = stuff((select top 5 ',' + quotename(column_name)
            from information_schema.columns
            where table_name = @tblname
            order by ordinal_position desc
            for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'')

set @sql = 'select '+@columns+' from '+quotename(@tblname)
exec (@sql)
```

Please advise if it works for you?

**EDIT**

I also added the functionality to specify top 200 and order by the Identity column descending:

```
declare @columns    varchar(max)
,       @sql        varchar(max)
,       @tblname    varchar(20)     =   '_btblInvoiceLines'

declare @idcolumn   varchar(max)    =   quotename((select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name = @tblname and COLUMNPROPERTY(object_id(TABLE_SCHEMA+'.'+TABLE_NAME), COLUMN_NAME, 'IsIdentity') = 1))

select @columns = stuff((select top 5 ',' + quotename(column_name)
            from information_schema.columns
            where table_name = @tblname
            order by ordinal_position desc
            for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'')

set @sql = 'select top 200'+@columns+' from '+quotename(@tblname)+' order by '+@idcolumn+' desc'
print(@sql)
exec (@sql)
```

Comment: its short than below answer. and works. so now storing it in stored procedure and parameter need to be taken of table name

Answer (score 1):

Just press **"End"** key when you are in the Results tab.
After that you will be at end of columns.

Comment: This is the only way to do this easily in SSMS!