# Why sql_variant datatype only returns string? in SQL-Server and VS# debugger?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have one table with  one column of type `sql_variant` and here's the data:

[image]

The output in SQL-Server is this:

[image]

The VS# debugger shows me this:

[image]

From [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-data-type-mappings) Mappings docs sql_variant will be mapped to .NET Object

So after all, why all data parsed as string? am i do something wrong. or missing something?

> Is it should be `Object{int}` and `Object{decimal}` and
>   `Object{string}`

Comment: The debugger is saying you have a `List<object>` so what exactly are you asking?

Comment: SQL Server is telling you that the BaseType of these values is `nvarchar`. How did you insert them?

Comment: with my hands o.0, not using sql query

Comment: The question should be `why are you using sql_variant?` What is the column's type and what is the actual type of those values? If they were inserted as strings, they are strings, even though they may look like numbers. In fact, the left alignment suggest they are just strings

Comment: `with my hands` doesn't mean anything. Did you type them in a grid? Then they are strings. Did you write an INSERT statement? Then they should be whatever type you used - `VALUES(1)` would insert a number while `VALUES('1')` would insert a string.

Comment: Guessing it stems from a comment I made [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59088118/is-there-a-way-to-select-last-n-columns-in-sql-server-results-tab/59088534?noredirect=1#comment104413408_59088534) @PanagiotisKanavos . Where I did say that it was not a recommendation and had caveats.

Comment: LARNU, yes exactly, and you made my head thinking about it? why not?

Comment: @deveton don't do that. Really don't do that, for no reason. Strong typing isn't a bug, it's a feature. It *doesn't* make your application less flexible. Database tables aren't files, they contain *entities* with specific attributes. Different entities, different tables.  Usinge Entity-Attribute-Value schemas is a *bad* idea which makes querying a LOT harder, validation impossible and harms performance as any indexes on the columns are essentially useless

Comment: @deveton even in Javascript, you use specific names for your functions and expect your parameters to have certain types. Never mind using objects and classes there, where you expect them to contain specific attributes and types. It's the same in relational databases. Now, if you have stuff that can be treated as a blob of ... stuff and *don't* need to use in querying, you can use the XML type or better yet, JSON. For example, an address is just informational data and could be stored in a JSON field. On the other hand, if you want to search, group or report by *country*, you'd put it in a field

Comment: To give a bit of background, as the question is missing it, @PanagiotisKanavos . The OP has a table that has a for ever changing definition; they keep adding (and i assume removing) columns; making a "I want only the last 5 columns `SELECT` query" impossible without dynamic SQL. They don't understand the dynamic SQL. I also said that the fact that a table's definition is constantly changing sounds like a design flaw, and should should tall; but due to the differing types `sql_variant` *might* be used, **however** it has caveats. it seems, however, that point has been missed/ignored.

Comment: The end eesult is that both this and the prior question are an XY of that the table's definition is for ever changing. Stop changing the definition, and stop having a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really really **had** to use `sql_variant`, you would need to insert the values via INSERT statements, and thus specify the datatype:

```sql
INSERT INTO test values (cast (1 as int))  
INSERT INTO test values (cast (20.5 as decimal(8, 2)))  
INSERT INTO test values (cast ('hello' as nvarchar))
```

Then when you run your query you see the values and data types:

[image]

Comment: Wait, so what is best way to store many settings of different types ? like Logo column which accept `Image` or `varbinary`, and some `bit` columns and some `nvarchar` columns ?

Comment: I create a Column for each setting? what if you have more than 150+ settings?

Comment: I'm not saying there aren't _any_ valid use cases, but the comments on your question explain the downsides far better than I could.

Answer (score -1):

sql_variant has many downsides
[See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62DYS.png)

Comment: This is more like a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: @Xiaosu is right but also why post an image of text instead of quoting the text?